# Redis master becoming slave of another master in docker environment

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I have configured redis-sentinel with one master and two slaves.

lets call this setup of three machines a cluster.

I have a lot of clusters running on a lot of docker containers.
On run time I manage the IP in the redis.conf file and sentinal.conf files.

My problem is;
The master node on cluster-1 somehow became slave of the master of cluster-2.
On Cluster-1 Master node I killed the redis and sentinel services, removed `slaveof <cluster-2 master ip> 6379` and then restarted redis service with the edited conf file.

The moment I start redis service, It again becomes slave of cluster-2 master redis.

I tried slaveof no one from inside redis-cli but within seconds the node again turn into slave.

All this is happening without even starting sentinel service.

What is happening here? are there other entries that I would have to delete?

**redis.conf**

```
bind 0.0.0.0


protected-mode no

port 6379

tcp-backlog 511


timeout 0

tcp-keepalive 300


daemonize no

supervised no

pidfile "/var/run/redis_6379.pid"

loglevel notice

logfile "/var/log/redis.log"
databases 16


save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000

stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes

rdbcompression yes

rdbchecksum yes

dbfilename "dump.rdb"

dir "/"



slave-serve-stale-data yes

slave-read-only yes

repl-diskless-sync no

repl-diskless-sync-delay 5



repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
slave-priority 100                                                                                                    

appendonly no


appendfilename "appendonly.aof"


appendfsync everysec


no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no


auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb

aof-load-truncated yes


lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000

slowlog-max-len 128


latency-monitor-threshold 0


notify-keyspace-events ""


hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64

list-max-ziplist-size -2

list-compress-depth 0

set-max-intset-entries 512

zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64

hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000

activerehashing yes

client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit slave 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10

aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
slaveof 192.168.60.38 6379 #this comes back again and again
```

Comment: sentinel config file may give you clues. As they might have details of existing master and slaves.

Comment: @NipunTalukdar I killed the sentinel service and deleted the file. All this happens without even starting sentinel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who faces the same problem.

Sentinel is designed to automatically detect another sentinels in the same network. 
So, Cluster-1 and Cluster-2 sentinels were all able to reach each other.

Sentinel of Cluster-1 became disloyal(pun intended) and rewrote the redis configuration of Cluster-1 redis making it slave of Cluster-2 Master redis.

Possible solutions;
1. Use Unique password between each redis setup. `requirepass` in redis configuration will be used.

2. Block traffic between different redis clusters.

3. Dont use sentinel all together.